# Unexpected result after running for loop

Tags: java

I am writing a class named as `Bank` and in the constructor. I am setting the initial balance of the account to `initialBalance`. `accounts` is a data member of `double[]` array type.

```
public Bank(int n, double initialBalance){
   accounts=new double[n];
   for( double i:accounts)
      i=initialBalance;
      System.out.println("setting accounts[3]"+accounts[3]);

 }
```

The problem i am facing is that I am trying to print any account's balance after loop. It is not showing the correct value.

Comment: what is the "correct" value and what "incorrect" values do you get.

Comment: System.out.println("setting accounts[3]"+accounts[3]);
As you use above line it's always show only one value...
please have some more home work on this..

Answer (score 2):

Should you be assigning `initialBalance` to each element of the `accounts` array...

```
public Bank(int n, double initialBalance){
    accounts=new double[n];
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        accounts[i]=initialBalance;
    }
    System.out.println("setting accounts[3]"+accounts[3]);
 }
```

Also, be careful when accessing an array element, it may not exist.  ie `accounts[3]`

Comment: array subscript is a double :-)

Comment: Ah moron :P - Thanks for the debug

Comment: I would use the regular forloop for this :-)

Comment: One should not copy and past OP code...I think time for sleep :P

Comment: What is the problem with this for- 
loopfor( double i:accounts)
      i=initialBalance;
assume i have 10 acccounts and intialBalance as 10K

Comment: `double` can't be used as an index into an array.  You can't do `accounts[i]` where `i` is a `double`, it doesn't make sense.  An array can only have a whole number index, not a half or quarter...

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++){
   accounts[i] = initialBalance;
}
System.out.println("setting accounts[3]"+accounts[3]);
```

KISS!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to modify an array using the foreach loop in Java. However, you can do it using the traditional `for` loop:

```
public Bank(int n, double initialBalance){
   accounts=new double[n];
   for(int i = 0; i < accounts.length; ++i)
      accounts[i] = initialBalance;
      System.out.println("setting accounts[i]"+accounts[i]);

 }
```

Also, another red flag: if a value less than 0 is passed as n, this will result in a `NegativeArraySizeException` if n is negative.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the correct code is as follows and it can help you:

```
public class Bank{
   public Bank(int n, double initialBalance){
   double accounts[]=new double[n];
   for(int i = 0; i<accounts.length; i++){
      accounts[i]=initialBalance;
      System.out.println("setting accounts[]"+accounts[i]);
   }//end of for
   }//end of constructor

  public static void main(String a[]){
  Bank b = new Bank(2, 12);

 }//end of main
}//end  of class
```